# DataGrid Bound Field throws TargetInvocationExeption

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, properties

this is my Code-Behind for a gridview.

```
gridViewLog.DataSource = LogManager.getEntriesByUser(UserManager.getCurrentUser());
gridViewLog.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

BoundField ev = new BoundField();
ev.DataField = "getMessage";
ev.HeaderText = "Ereignis";
gridViewLog.Columns.Add(ev);

BoundField name = new BoundField();
name.DataField = "User.Name";
name.HeaderText = "Name";
gridViewLog.Columns.Add(name);

gridViewLog.DataBind();
```

LogManager.getEntriesByUser(int id) return a List of LogEntry-Objects.
The LogEntry-Class looks like this:

```
public class LogEntry
{
    private User user;
    public User User
    {
        get {
            if(user == null)
                user = UserManager.getUserById(userId);
            return user;
        }
    }

public virtual String getMessage
    {
        get
        {
    return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine. But when my List contains on object of the following class I get an Exeption.

```
    class NeuerKunde : LogEntry
{

    public override String getMessage
    {
        get { return "Test2"; }
    } 
}
```

The Exeption:
"Der Eigenschaftenaccessor getMessage für das Model.LogEntry-Objekt hat folgende Ausnahme verursacht: Das Objekt stimmt mit dem Zieltyp nicht überein"

Translation: "The Property-Accessor getMessage for the Model.LogEntry-Object caused an exeption: The object does not match the target type."

The innerExeption is a TargetExeption and says the same.

Trying to access the Property without reflection works fine.

I think it has something to do with the gridView trying to invoke the getMessage-Property but I've no idea how to fix it...

Anyone?